# V8 Cannot set ObjectTemplate with name "console"

Tags: c++, v8

I try to set a global object named console, but that specific name causes a crash and to me it seems like it's telling me that the object already exists. I can though set it to anything else. Why can I not set the object to name "console"?

V8 Version is 6.5.254.6

Error

```
# Fatal error in ../../src/objects.cc, line 6007
# Debug check failed: !it.IsFound().
```

Code Snippet

```
isolate->Enter();
v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

// Create globals
auto globalObj = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

// Create console object
auto consoleObj = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

// Log
auto logcb = [](V8CallbackArgs args) {
    auto& log = Log::Instance();
    for (size_t i = 1; i < args.Length(); i++)
        log << *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[i]);
    log << std::endl;
};
consoleObj->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "log"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, logcb));

// Set global object
globalObj->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "console"), consoleObj); // nonono cannot have it console, con is ok though

// Create script context
context = v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>>(isolate, v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr, globalObj));

{
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context.Get(isolate));
    v8::TryCatch tc(isolate);

    auto source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(src.c_str());
    auto script = v8::Script::Compile(source);

    if (script->Run().IsEmpty() && CV8ScriptRuntime::isDebug) {
        v8loge "Error loading script \"" << filepath << "\n" << std::endl
            << "Exception: " << *v8::String::Utf8Value(tc.Exception()) << std::endl
            << "Stack trace: " << *v8::String::Utf8Value(tc.StackTrace()) << std::endl << Log::White;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're making a correct observation. What is your question?

Comment: Why can I not set an object with name "console", and if it is predefined, can I unset the object? I posted the error I get when I try to set an object with name "console".
To me it seems that "console" object already exists when initializing a V8 script. but as far as I know v8 shouldn't have console object set by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. When V8 initializes a `Context`, it installs a global `console` object into it, and assumes (guarded by a check) that a property with that name does not exist yet. When you provide your own "console", that check fails.

If you want to overwrite V8's built-in `console`, you'll have to create the `Context` first (via `v8::Context::New`), then delete (or overwrite) the `console` property on its global object.

If all you wanted was to have a `console` object in your embedder just like the one you know from browsers, then I'm happy to inform you that this work has already been done and you can simply use it :-)

Comment: How would I be able to delete or overwrite the console.log function to be specific?

Comment: You already have the global object in `globalObj`; you can use `v8::Object`'s `Get` method to get its "console" object, and then either  `Delete` to delete its "log" method or `Set` to overwrite it. Or you could simply execute the script "delete console.log" in your new context.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize contexts without console object preset?

Comment: No, sorry. It's built in like the other builtins.